# Help with Proposition 13.2.9 in Ireland and Rosen

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

I'm currently self studying Ireland and Rosen's *A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory* and got stuck on the proof of **Proposition 13.2.9**. In this proof, $p$ is a prime not dividing $m$, $D, D_m$ denote the ring of algebraic integers in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p,\zeta_m)=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{pm})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$ respectively (where $\zeta_m$ is the primitive mth root of unity). The authors have shown that $pD=(P_1P_2...P_{g'})^{e'(p-1)}$ where $P_i$ are distinct prime ideals of degrees $f'$. On the other hand it is shown that $pD_m=\widetilde{P_1}\widetilde{P_2}...\widetilde{P_g}$ where $\widetilde{P_i}$ are distinct prime ideals of degrees $f$. The authors then claimed "by considering the prime decomposition of $\widetilde{P_i}D$ and comparing the equations we see $f' \geq f$ and $g' \geq g$". However I cannot see why the first inequality should hold.

Would anyone please help me out with this part of the proof? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: If two ideals are the same in an extension L of K, then intersecting them with K shows that they are the same in K.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer I'm not sure how the result you stated applies, can you please be a bit more explicit?

Comment: Two ideals cannot become equal in extensions of number fields (more precisely in the respective rings of integers). You probably will have to use integral closure if you fill in all the details. This implies that $g' \ge g$.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer yes, I see how they cannot be equal but I'm not sure if they can have the same prime ideals as factors

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer I got why $g' \geq g$ now, thanks for the assistance. Can you also help me with why  $f' \geq f$?

Comment: I don't remember what IR have already shown at this point, but if you know that f is the residue class degree then you're done since the number of residue classes cannot decrease in extensions.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer I'm not sure I understand what you mean by residue class degree. However I did figure out why the inequality works (finally!) by constructing an injective map (perhaps the same principle at work ultimately). Anyways, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

After some time I think I came up with a valid reason, I'll post it here for others' reference:
Consider the mapping $d+\widetilde{P_i} \mapsto d+P_j$, from $D_m/\widetilde{P_i}$ to $D/P_j$ where $P_j$ is a prime ideal factor of $\widetilde{P_i}D$. One can show this mapping is well-defined and injective. Thus $p^f=|D_m/\widetilde{P_i}| \leq |D/P_j|=p^{f'}$.